# set all int / imageresource / clicklistener ext in one while code

Tags: java, android, image, while-loop, int

I have got 30 ints. and 30 images. i want to set all of them same in one code
like this  (in Java with for android
)

my int values are like i0 , i1 , i2

```
int x = 0 ;
while ( x<30) {
//set ix = 0;
x++;
}
```

or

```
"x starts from 0 to 29"
 ax.setImageResource
```

how can I make int / images same programatically

Comment: Android isn't a programming language, it's a platform. Which language are you using? (looks like C# or C++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int x=0;x<30;x++)
{
   ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("a"+x, "id", getPackageName()));
   img.setImageResource(getIdentifier("i"+x , "drawable", getPackageName()));
}
```

**EDIT**

How can I make it for int and onclicklistener ?

set `OnClickListener` on each `ImageView` object by doing `img.setOnClickListener(...)` in the loop...

For your ints you can use an array but if their variable names are important then you can try doing this:

```
Map<String,Integer> myints=new HashMap<String,Integer>(){
   {
      put("nameX",0);
      put("nameX",1);
      ...and so on... 
   }
};
```

Then do this in your loop

```
int num=myints.get("name"+x);
```

You can use the same method with other objects just replace `Integer` with the object you need...